# Insert data into Always Encrypted column using stored procedure in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption, entity-framework, always-encrypted

I am facing an issue while trying to insert data into SQL table which is having encrypted columns in it.

Following is my approach.

I have created a table with three columns: **[ID], [Name], [Password]**.

**[Name]** and **[Password]** columns are encrypted.
with **COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [Test_CEK], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256')**

- I have set "**Column Encryption Setting = Enabled**"
- I have set "**Parameterization for Always Encrypted**"

And I have created a procedure to insert records into Test table as follows:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTest


@name varchar(50),

@pwd varchar(max)

AS

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Name] ,[Password]) VALUES (@name, @pwd)

END 

GO
```

When I try to insert record using the above procedure I am getting error as shown below.

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure InsertTest, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(1) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'Test_CEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDB') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

I want to insert data into SQL table through stored procedure.

Do not want to use ADO.Net for SQL connection.

Want to implement the same using EntityFramework.

Comment: Can you show us the callin code pls

Comment: Currently I am trying to insert data using above mentioned stored procedure [InsertTest] in MSSQL.

EXEC InsertTest 'Test','Test'

Comment: Can you share your CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: **My CREATE TABLE Statement**
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](50) COLLATE Lat_Gen_B ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'Algorithm-AES-256') NOT NULL,
 [Password] [varchar](max) COLLATE Lat_Gen_B ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'Algorithm-AES-256') NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO.